# Case when Random.Value

Tags: sql, oracle, random, case-when

My query is built on multiple 'case when' statements, and I am trying to add a random sample of about 10 records to this mix.

I guess I'm looking for something like:

```
 Case when (select dbms_random.random DOC_NUM (x10) then 'Random' else '-' end rand_doc
```

If something like that is possible in a case when?

There's no specific criteria I want to look for, but if it helps in a case when statement then I can add 'doc_num Like '%5%'' for example, as this would still give me a decent random sample (as the doc_num is 8 numbers long)

Output example:

```
12345678 'random'
12346789 '-'
12348790 '-'
21212120 '-'
65656565 'random'
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: You want to *add* random records to your result or you want to take a random sample of 10 records from them?

Comment: I want to flag 10 of them with 'random', so Take a random sample of 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (order by dbms_random.random) <= 10
             then 'random'
             else '-'
        end) as rand_doc
from t;
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was after, thank you for the quick reply Gordon.